# Python: Not getting the response for Message Back action in MS Teams Adaptive Cards

Tags: python, json, flask, bots, microsoft-teams

I am new to Python and have been trying to integrate it with MS Teams using an outgoing webhook. I have created a simple web service to handle post request using flask and I am hosting it using ngrok and the resulting URL from ngrok have been used as the Outgoing webhook callback URL in teams.

I am able to receive message in my service and send an adaptive card as response. But if I fill out the information and click Submit I get 'Something went wrong. Please try again' error and I am not receiving anything in my service.

Any help will be highly appreciated.[Screenshot for Adaptive card in Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ujpJ.png)

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import hmac, hashlib, base64
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/testjson',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':

            # Reply
            data = request.get_json()
            channel = data['channelId']
            message_type = data['type']
            sender = data['from']['name']
            sender_id = data['from']['id']
            message_format = data['textFormat']
            message = data['text']
            conversation_id = data['conversation']['id']

            # Authenticate
            security_token = b"sWYCgxib4hRcuHSKcKJk6w8FF6dVOa3mgmgK6thBMBg="
            request_data = request.get_data()
            digest = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(security_token), msg=request_data,
                              digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
            signature = base64.b64encode(digest).decode()

            # Verify that HMAC header == signature
            if request.headers.get('Authorization').split(' ')[1] == signature:
                return jsonify({
                        "type": "message",
                        "text": "hi",
                        "attachments": [{
                            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                            "content": {
                                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                                "version": "1.0",
                                "body": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "Present a form and submit it back to the originator"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Input.Text",
                                        "id": "firstName",
                                        "placeholder": "What is your first name?"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Input.Text",
                                        "id": "lastName",
                                        "placeholder": "What is your last name?"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "actions": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                                        "title": "Submit",
                                        "data": {
                                             "msteams": {
                                                "type": "messageBack",
                                                "displayText": "I clicked this button",
                                                "text": "text to bots",
                                                "value": "{\"bfKey\": \"bfVal\", \"conflictKey\": \"from value\"}"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }]
                    })
        else:
            print("hi")

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you try to open Teams in web browser share the console log you receive at the time of clicking the submit button. Also does it hit the on_message_activity() method on lick of the method.

Comment: How long do it take for your service to send the response? i think teams need a response within 5 sec from the outgoing api call has been made