# Adaptive Card's messageBack action for msteams provided by outgoing webhook fails with "The resource URL is misformatted."

Tags: botframework, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I have followed [Extend Microsoft Teams Exercise - Create outgoing webhooks 3-exercise-outgoing-webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-webhooks-connectors/3-exercise-outgoing-webhooks) to build a MS Teams Outgoing webhook, and successfully it returns planet themed Adaptive Cards.

However, when I add a new messageBack action, following guidance on [special Adaptive Card functionality that is specific to the Microsoft Teams channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-actions), it fails in its reply to the webhook.

The added action I have used is copied verbatim and added to the actions list for `planetDisplayCard.json`:

```json
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "title": "Learn more on Wikipedia"
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Click me for messageBack",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
            "type": "messageBack",
            "displayText": "I clicked this button",
            "text": "text to bots",
            "value": "{\"bfKey\": \"bfVal\", \"conflictKey\": \"from value\"}"
        }
      }
    }
```

The card renders in Teams, but when the button is clicked the following happen:

- Unexpected: We see `Something went wrong. Please try again.`
- Expected: The chat includes the `displayText` "I clicked this button"
- Unexpected: the dev tools report a `400` code return from the `POST` to `https://emea.ng.msg.teams.microsoft.com/v1/agents/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-redacted/invoke`with the body `{"errorCode":201,"message":"The resource URL is misformatted."}`

  - the tools show the request body `{clientMessageId: "11862533962269802517" conversation: {id: "19:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxredacted@thread.skype;messageid=1603494001316"} imdisplayname: "My Name" messageType: "RichText/Media_Card" name: "messageback" serverMessageId: "1603539459992" text: "text to bots" value: {bfKey: "bfVal", conflictKey: "from value"} bfKey: "bfVal" conflictKey: "from value"}`

I have also seen this same problem with a HeroCard messageBack CardAction for my own hosted webhook service; but in trying to diagnose the problem I have reproduced with same fail with the Yeoman Generator for Microsoft Teams on my local dev environment.

A picture to illustrate
[image: my dev environment where it is all going wrong]

Do `messageBack` Actions work with Outgoing Webhooks in MS Teams ?

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/61825279/310809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this exact scenario, but an outgoing webhook is -similar- in some ways to a bot, but not as fully featured, and can't handle multiple steps in an action like this, to my knowledge. The "Card Actions" article you've linked to basically says as much in the intro paragraph:

> Cards used by bots and messaging extensions...

As a result, I'd suggest rather building a full-blown Teams bot for this scenario. You can have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots) to get started on that, and of course ask any questions here on S.overflow if you're stuck.

Comment: The outgoing webhooks suited a set of existing AWS Lamda (  exposed by Gateway APIs) and I am looking to make them more accessible with a simple menu system. messageBack buttons are just nicer than  simpler alternatives, if I must keep it simple. Researching - there is nothing explicit ruling them in or out for webhooks - what's a 'messaging extension'?

Comment: I think the problem is, in a bot context, Teams understands the endpoint to send the response to, whereas it doesn't actually have such a thing for a webhook (I know the -webhook itself- is registered, but this scenario of adaptive card + return is different). "message extension" is a different kind of functionality altogether - it's adding functionality into the context menu for a single message (like the "actions" menu), or putting an app into the "compose" box at the bottom (like the wikipedia example you've probably seen) - just goolge it